# Copying Bootstrap File to Nested Directory

Tags: php, magento, session

So I've copied `index.php` to `directory/index.php` and modified it so it looks as follows:

```
<?php

require_once '../app/Mage.php';

umask(0);

Mage::app();

$itemCount = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
echo "Items in cart: " . $itemCount . "<br />";

$isLoggedIn = Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
echo "User logged in: " . (int)$isLoggedIn;
```

I'm running into a problem with sessions though, where if I log out on the main site and log back in my copied file will say that I'm logged out.

The only culprit I can find is two `PHPSESSID` cookies, one set in `/`, the other set in `/directory`.  Removing them and trying again will fix the issue.

How can I make this copied file reflect accurate session data from the main?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all that needs to be done is to set the cookie path in System > Configuration > Web

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/19582/#t66564